# x-ua compatible not working every time

Tags: internet-explorer-9, x-ua-compatible

My website includes the metatag: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" /`>

However for some of my users (small amount) using IE9 this is not being applied and I am having to tell them to appy compatibility mode themselves

I have it placed directly after the opening of the `<head>` tag.

Has anyone else had such experiences and know of a way to resolve this?

Comment: Ran into the same issue today - did you ever figure anything out with this?

Comment: caused by some users running anti virus avg software. They inject link tracking scripts which meant the x-ua-compatible tag was not the first tag after the header, hence it wasn't applied. Fix is to set the x-ua-compatible response header on the server

Answer (score 1):

`<meta>`'s have to be right after the opening `<head>` tag

Answer (score 0):

I had this too, but asked the users to clear their IE browser cache and that fixed it for them.

Even though it was clearly there when you view source, it's as if IE was ignoring it until the cache was cleared.